# How to change disabled <TextInput/> color

Tags: react-native

React native changing  text color when passing props `editable=false`.
[image: screenshot of text input]

How i can change that color of text input ?, i have read the documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput but not getting helped

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are changing the text input color you can update the style based on the prop:

```
<TextInput style={{ color: editable ? 'red' : 'blue' }} ... />
```

If you are trying to change the place holder color, you can do it in a similar manner but with the [placeHolderTextColor](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#placeholdertextcolor) prop instead:

```
<TextInput placeHolderTextColor={ editable ? 'red' : 'blue' } ... />
```

Comment: Thanks !! you are awesome, i done with `props.editable == false && { color: undefined }` because i have use default color of text input value

Answer (score 0):

do not use editable={false}.

Place your input inside a simple view and use the props pointerEvents="none", so your input won't be touched.

```html
<S. onPress={handleOpenModalFuel}>
            <View pointerEvents="none">
              <S.LabelInput>Fuel</S.LabelInput>
              <MyInput
                placeholder="Fuel"
                value={selectFuel.value}
                defaultValue={formatFuel(vehicle?.fuel_type_id)}
              />
            </View>
</S.ContainerInputSelect>
```